# HTTP Error 404: Deployment of a Web API (minimal API NET 7) on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I probably have a setup problem on IIS (it's a web server with real URL domain, so accessible from external at any time). I have created a Web API with minimal API NET 7. Before testing out authetification, I tried to reach an endpoint first. I named this endpoint **/api/test** and defined it as **[AllowAnonymous]**. On the development server via Swagger everything is already running (also the login or generation of tokens). But in the release web api version I commented out Swagger.

Now when I install the web app on IIS server, then when I call the app via IIS server (but also when I enter the address in browser itself) I get the message: **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**
Detailed error information is:

- Module: IIS Web Core
- Notification: MapRequestHandler
- Handler: StaticFile
- Error code: 0x80070002
- Requested URL: http://api.testapp.com:64591/api/test
- Physical path: C:\inetpub\wwroot\Testapp\api\test
- Login method: Anonymous
- User login: Anonymous

Most likely causes:

- The specified directory or file does not exist on this web server.
- The URL contains a spelling error.
- Access to the file is restricted by a custom filter or module such as URLScan.

But if I run the app in the console via **dotnet Testapp.dll**, then it is started and if I then enter the URL http://localhost:5000/api/test in the browser, then I get the data.

So it can only be that something has gone wrong with the IIS App setup. By the way I also have **ASP.NET Core 7.0 Runtime (v7.0.1) - Windows Hosting Bundle** installed. When setting up the app on IIS I used the following guide: http://www.technical-recipes.com/2018/running-asp-net-web-api-services-in-iis/

Can anyone help me with any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Following Lex's suggestion (see his comment below), I installed the Jexus Manager software and ran diagnostics. Here is the report:

---

### IMPORTANT: This report might contain confidential information. Mask such before sharing with others.

System Time: 15.12.2022 10:18:45
Processor Architecture: AMD64
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
Server Type: IIS

Scan 28 installed module(s).
ASP.NET Core module version 2 is installed for .NET Core 3.1 and above: C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll (17.0.22323.1).

### Scan 44 registered handler(s).
No valid ASP.NET Core handler is registered for this web site.
To run ASP.NET Core on IIS, please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index for more details.

**EDIT 2**

I am getting a little closer to the issue. The fundamental error was that I used the app files from the release folder and not from Publish!

I have now copied the app correctly and when I start the app in IIS, browser opens and I can request the data via the Api link!
So locally on the server it works, the problem I have now is that it does not work from external. I get the message:

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

The message also appears in the MAUI application which should use this web api:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond properly after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (api.website.com:64500)

I started Diagnostic Tool again and I get the following output:

---

IMPORTANT: This report might contain confidential information. Mask such before sharing with others.

- System Time: 15.12.2022 10:33:27
- Processor Architecture: AMD64
- OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
- Server Type: IIS
- Scan 28 installed module(s).
- ASP.NET Core module version 2 is installed for .NET Core 3.1 and above: C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll (17.0.22323.1).

Scan 45 registered handler(s).

- Found a valid ASP.NET Core handler as { Name: aspNetCore, Path: *, - State: Enabled, Module: AspNetCoreModuleV2, Entry Type: Local }.
  Visual C++ runtime is detected (expected: 14.0, detected: 14.24.28127.4 built by: vcwrkspc): C:\Windows\system32\msvcp140.dll.
  The application pool 'WebApplication1' is used.
  Pool identity is IIS AppPool\WebApplication1
  Please ensure pool identity has read access to the content folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApplication1.
  Pool bitness is 64 bit
  Scan aspNetCore section.
  "processPath": dotnet.
  "arguments": .\WebApplication1.dll.
  "hostingModel": inprocess.

- In-process hosting model is detected. To avoid 500.xx errors, make sure that the bitness of published artifacts matches the application pool bitness
  Framework dependent deployment is detected. Skip bitness check.
  Found runtime config file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.runtimeconfig.json.
  Runtime is 7.0.0.

Comment: You will have to run a report and let us know what's recorded, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Sounds like `web.config` does not take effect.

Comment: Thanks Lex. I did it. The report is to long, so I put it in my post under EDIT.

Comment: I have posted my new knowledge (and problems) under EDIT 2 (see above)

Answer (score 1):

Now it works. If someone else has similar problems (Minimal Api application under NET 7 on IIS), then here are a few tips:

- if you release the application, you have to do it via Publish (because e.g. also Web-Config is under Release not generated)
- .NET Core Hosting Bundle must be installed on the IIS server.
- make sure to open the required ports under Firewall, otherwise external access is not possible
- if there should be problems then it makes sense to install the app Jexus Manager and use diagnostic tool in the app.

So, hope I have not missed anything.

Comment: The publish step (and other important steps) was very well documented under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=netcore-cli#publish-and-deploy-the-app (VS/CLI/VS for Mac are all covered).