# How to configure IIS from a webapi that was in net3.1 in net7.0

Tags: c#, webapi

**How to configure IIS from a webapi that was in net3.1 in net7.0**
**?**

I have an application in net7 that should run on the server on top of iis, but I don't know how to configure it in net7, before there was a solution made in 3.1

What I have today:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("It was not possible to get executing assembly information");

var options = new WebApplicationOptions()
{
    ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory,
    Args = args,
    ApplicationName = assembly.GetName().Name
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);

if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
}

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", true);

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddLogger();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Comment: Does this helps your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803135/http-error-404-deployment-of-a-web-api-minimal-api-net-7-on-iis